# Pipenv Locking Failed: Error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, pipenv

I have a clean virtual environment that I setup with pipenv. I need to install a package called wrds that seems to have `psycopg2` as a dependency. I get this error after running `pipenv install wrds`.

The full error says:

```
pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

So I ran `pipenv install psycopg2-binary` and got the same error. Really don't understand what is going on here. I don't want to build psycopg2 from source because I need my other team members to be able to just run `pipenv install`.

Edit: Just found this which provides some useful information. https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3991

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and on Mac OS, I solved it using the homebrew package manager

```
brew install postgresql
```

after installing postgresql pipenv succeed in locking environment